# Upgrade to Ubuntu 19.10 led me to Firmware Bug TSC_DEADLINE + ACPI BIOS Error

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel

After a reboot during the update to Ubuntu 19.04 to 19.10, I arrived at a boot error following the GRUB boot loader. My machine is an HP Pavilion Gaming Notebook. I use it dual boot with Windows 10. The error messages begin with:

```
[0.0393321] [Firmware Bug] TSC_DEADLINE disabled due to Errata: please update microcode to version 0xb2 (or later)
```

There is also a kernel panic message:

```
[0.844241] Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
```

I've attached an image of the final output screen. Can anyone help me return Ubuntu to a working state?
[image: Boot error messages]

Comment: Are you able to get to the GRUB menu? If so, what happens if you boot to the prior kernel?

Comment: Yes! There were two older kernels on the relevant submenu. There were some errors, but no kernel panic; then a black screen; then the desktop appeared. I might try upgrading again.

Comment: `sudo do-release-upgrade` reports that there is no new release. Indeed `lsb_release -a` indicates this is Ubuntu 19.10. `sudo apt-get upgrade` fails with "dpkg was interrupted...".

Comment: What is the model and serial # of your computer. I'm trying to locate it at support.hp.com.

Comment: Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, open a terminal window by pressing Ctrl+Alt+T, type `sudo fdisk -l`, identify the `/dev/XXXX` device name for your "Linux Filesystem", then type `sudo fsck -f /dev/XXXX`, replacing `XXXX` with the number you found earlier. Repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors, then reboot and update your question with the results.

Comment: Can you boot into Windows?

Comment: Running `sudo apt-get upgrade` under the older kernel suggested that I run `sudo dpkg --configure -a`. I tried that, and it started a long process which looked like the Ubuntu upgrade. After that, it looks like all is good. The default boot option for Ubuntu now works, and I am writing this under Ubuntu 19.10. (Yes, the Windows boot was still working.) Thanks for the kernel boot suggestion @heynnema. (I had also tried a USB with Ubuntu live, but it was running painfully slowly.)

Comment: Great news! Good job! I put together a quick answer for you. Please remember to accept it for me, by clicking the checkmark icon just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments...

Upgrade to 19.10 failed, and was crashing on reboot. Windows still booted fine.

At the GRUB menu, selected the prior kernel and were able to boot.

Then did...

`sudo apt-get upgrade`

`sudo dpkg --configure -a`

And rebooted into 19.10 and it's all working now!

Comment: Had the exact same issue. The same commands fixed it for me, except I had to run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` first and `sudo apt-get upgrade` second.